# Format List Data c# Horizontal to vertically

Tags: c#, linq

For example, how can I group the following records by `GroupId` using LINQ, and (thus merging all rows in each group into one)

```
var list = new List<Foo>()
{ 
    new Foo() { GroupId = 0, ValueA = 10, ValueB = 100 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 30, ValueB = 700 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 40, ValueB = 500 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 80, ValueB = 300 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 },
    new Foo() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 }
};
```

Please let me know how can i add these with seperated comma **not add these values** 
Expected result is :

```
| GroupId | ValueA | ValueB    |
|---------|--------|-----------|
|    0    |   10   |   100     |
|    1    | 30,40  | 700,500   |
|    2    |80,20,20|300,200,200|
```

i can add these with code :

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.GroupId)
.Select(g => new { GroupId = g.Key, 
                   ValueA = g.Sum(i => i.ValueA), 
                   ValueB = g.Sum(i => i.ValueB)});
```

but i need show the values with seperated comma
Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Join` and select as strings instead:

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.GroupId)
    .Select(g => new { 
         GroupId = g.Key,
         ValueA = String.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.ValueA.ToString())), 
         ValueB = String.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.ValueB.ToString()))
    });
```

Comment: thanks for reply but a error shows `cannot convert System.collection.genric.ienumerable<anonymoustype> to system.collection.genric.list<Anonymous>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the string.Join command to concatenate the individidual numbers with a separator (,).